# jquery find specific word on src and remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I need to find this word 500x462 in a src image att and remove it . Right now the image ends with 500x462 + jpg and i want it to end with image name + jpg

I forgot to say that the website is a wordpress theme generated by php so i need the script to run after the php

Heres a example of the code i want to change

Comment: You can try : $('#imageID').attr('src').indexOf('500x462') will find the word

Comment: Use string `replace` with a regex? Please show your code too :)

Comment: @DinoMyte why not use lastIndexOf() [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp)

Comment: `$('.img').attr('src',(_,s)=>s.replace('500x462', ''))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a quick jQuery function to do this for you. First parameter is a jQuery selector and second parameter is the string you would like to remove.

```js
window.srcRemoveString = function(selector, string) {
    $(selector).each(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var filename = src.split('/');
        filename = filename[filename.length - 1];
        var newFilename = filename.replace(string, '');
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace(filename, newFilename));
  });
}

srcRemoveString('img', '500x462');
```

Comment: This would remove '500x462' anywhere in the src and OP is trying to remove only it only at the end

Comment: This will also replace all image src attributes **with the same value!** You need to iterate the collection of `img` if you do it this way.

Comment: Thank you DinoMyte and Gone Coding I have updated the function to address the issues you brought up.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex:

```
$("img").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr("src").replace(/[\d]{3}x[\d]{3}/, ''));
});
```

This will remove **any** sequence of [3 digits][the letter x][3 digits] in all images `src` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery and [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), so for example:

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x462.jpg">
```

JQuery:

```
var string = $("img").attr("src");
var new_string = string.replace('500x462', '');
alert(new_string);
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/fr23naw9/).

Comment: `.replace()` is native JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: Yeah i meant use jquery AND .replace()

Comment: Doesn't seem to work , and i forgot to say that the site is a wordpress theme generated by php

Comment: Wordpress? and you didn't mention that? You'll need to edit the PHP non the js

Comment: is there no way to do it with js , i mean i chcked the php and the searchpage(since its there) gets the img from a block that its php itself and it doesn't specify the word 500x462 there and i got confused

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the image src always ends with a file extension.

```
  <img src="ABC500x462blah500x462.jpg"> 

  <script>
    var src = $('img').attr('src');
    var textToCheck = '500x462';
    $('img').attr('src', src.split('.')[0].replace(new RegExp(textToCheck +"$"),"")  // check for the text occurring at the end
+ "." + src.split('.')[1]);
        alert($('img').attr('src'));
     </script>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/mu2d6qr7/

Answer (score 0):

Best way to split text in image source

```
jQuery(".size-post-thumbnail").each(function(){
                let src = jQuery(this).attr("src").split("-220x146");
                    src = src[0]+src[1];
                jQuery(this).attr("src", src);
jQuery(this).removeAttr('srcset');
            });
```